# Единственное и множественное число в заимствованиях

Tags: заимствования

Скажите, пожалуйста, допускается ли употребление слова *"пилинг"* во множественном числе.

Comment: пи́линг
a, мн. нет, м.
[англ. peeling < to peel — соскабливать, снимать]  Толковый словарь иноязычных слов
Л. П. Крысин https://herzena.ru/index.php/words/show/12038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу такого решения в словаре.

Дело в том, что это процесс, как, например, рисование, беганье. Поэтому написано, что нет множественного. На то, что это процесс, указывает окончание *-ing* в английском (*peeling*). Форму множественного числа образовать можно, но её использование будет нарушать стилистику.